# Grid view to stay intact once imageview image is changed

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a game in Android where in the alpha value is changed once the image in the imageview and the image in the grid view match. If the number of matches are equal to 4, I need to change the image in the imageview and again compare with the images in the grid view.

I change the image in the imageview using imageView.setImageResource(q);

The image gets changed but the grid view disappears. Could you please tell me what I need to do for the grid view to change intact?

I tried gridView.invalidateViews(); but in vain. I also created a new imageadapter with the same context but it still did not work. Any help would be really great!

```
package com.example.despicablemehunt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     final public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon2,
                R.drawable.icon3, R.drawable.icon4,
                R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon2,
                R.drawable.icon3, R.drawable.icon4,
                R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon2,
                R.drawable.icon3, R.drawable.icon4,
                R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon2,
                R.drawable.icon3, R.drawable.icon4

        };
     int i=0;
     int p=0;
     final Integer q=0;
     public Context mContext;
     List<Integer> imagesArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(mThumbIds));
     Integer [] tempArrayList;
     public static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
     public static final Integer[] mImageIds = 
        { R.drawable.icon1, R.drawable.icon2, R.drawable.icon3,R.drawable.icon4 };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final long time=  System.currentTimeMillis();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Collections.shuffle(imagesArrayList);
        tempArrayList =   (Integer[])(imagesArrayList.toArray(new Integer[imagesArrayList.size()]));

         final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            final Integer q = mImageIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mImageIds.length)];
            final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            iv.setImageResource(q);

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                      if(getResources().getDrawable(q).getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(tempArrayList[arg2]).getConstantState()))
                      {
                          if(p==5)
                          {
                            /*final long time1=  System.currentTimeMillis();
                            if ((time1-time)> 20)
                            {

                            }*/
                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DONE DONE DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          }
                          arg1.setAlpha((float) 0.4);
                          if((++i)== 4)
                          {
                              gridView.setAlpha((float)0.0);
                              p++;


                             final Integer q = mImageIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mImageIds.length)];
                            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) iv;
                            imageView.setImageResource(q);
                             i=0;
                            gridView.invalidate();
                          }


                      }
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        // Keep all Images in array


        // Constructor
        public ImageAdapter(Context c){
            mContext = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setImageResource(tempArrayList[position]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(50, 50));
            return imageView;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: any crash logd, or a little code would be much needed

Answer (score 0):

1. To refresh the gridview you have to use gridView.invalidateViews(); So change it
2. after 4 correct click on gridview image why are you setting alpha 0 in gridview. So just remove the line

   gridView.setAlpha((float)0.0);

   //setting alpha causing the gridview invisible

so your code should be like this

```
if ((++i) == 4) {
p++;
final Integer q = mImageIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mImageIds.length)];
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) iv;
iv.setImageResource(q);
i = 0;
gridView.invalidateViews();
}
```

hope this will help
Thanks